# Example for Multiple jQuery AutoSuggest plugin on Single Form

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, autocomplete, autosuggest

HI I am using this Jquery Plugin http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin
I have successfully develop this code in my form . but i need this plugin three times in my form(page). I am new in this plugin. Please help me how can i put more than one Autosuggest and retrive its value in a one form..

This is my code for autosuggest..
//javascrpit code

```
$("#CC").autoSuggest("loadcontact.html", {minChars: 2, matchCase: true});
            $("#TO").autoSuggest("loadcontact.html", {minChars: 2, matchCase: true});



            $("#send").click(function(){
                alert($(".as-values").val());//getting currect value

                alert($("#CC").val());//getting undefined...

            });
```

//JSP code
input type="text" name="test"  value="" class="hihi" id="TO"/>
input type="text" name="test1"  value="" class="hihi" id="CC"/>

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

your question got closed so here is the answer ... see the *demo $ documentatio* of the jquery autocomplete plugin [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

here is the [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/7Nqfs/) related to your question

availableTags,availableTags2 and availableTags3 act as the source for the auto complete you can change it as per your requirement

Comment: Thanks For your answer this is a great demo. i like it but i need multiple selection in auto suggest  see demo http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin .. If you know then please help me. Thanks in adv